# Quizzing application: the best way to stop sessions expiring (codeigniter, PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-state, web-testing

I have a live quizzing website which has thousands of users taking quizzes, whilst logged in to the site. On occasion, several users report that their quizzing results are not submitted, and in the error reports their usernames are not displayed, leading us to believe this is a session issue.

If sessions are expiring, we are considering options that would do all of the following:

a) prevent sessions from expiring

b) not take away from the performance of the application

c) not drain the memory (having unnecessary open sessions)

#1 **One option was to do the following in config.php:**

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0. It is currently 7200.
```

I've read somewhere that apps like facebook do this, but it also means that you have potentially a huge amount of sessions unnecessarily open. For an application of our size, is this the best option?

**#2 Create a pop up that notifies the user that their session is about to expire.**

The issue with this, from my understanding, is that will be making server calls, and along with all the other things happening on the site (it's heavily db driven) it will decrease performance. Furthermore, it seems obvious that if the user is active, the session will not expire and if they are not, they won't see the message - so is there any point?

**#3 Checking to see if there is somewhere in the code that is somehow killing the session (not sure how to go about doing this).**

What I am after is some comments, with considered explanations, on the above suggested solutions or for additional suggestions and implementations that we have missed.

Currently, as mentioned, several users do not appear to realise that they have been logged out, take a quiz, and then find that they have no results on submission. We are not a banking website so the idea that someone may log on while a user is away is not our greatest concern.....with that in mind - any suggestions?

Comment: In your case it's better to switch to Staltless session , using Token Authentication ,like JWT , or using an already provider service like Oauth ...

Comment: Could you explain this in more explicit and outlined detail in a suggested answer please? Timelines for implementation and other reference points as well as the working understand behind it.

Comment: so basically JWT allows authentication and signed transfer of information WITHOUT sessions? From a brief read, it appears you'll have a similar situation with tokens...as in they cannot/should not be stored for longer than necessary etc.

Comment: yes , but it prevent session storing server side . and I' think quiz will no longer get 1 hour of time :),

Comment: In an existing web application, how long do you think your suggested JWT solution would take to implement?

Comment: Sorry but it depends on the complexity of the app , you should now that all the server generated html should be in client side that consumes rest (json data from server) , I'm searching if possible to integrate JWT with codeigniter without using rest services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227080/discussion-between-sadhil-spring-and-misscomputing).